# ElasticSearch Endpoint API Stream not working

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, .net-core

I executed the below script using Kibana to clear the cache. And after executing this, My frontend API data is not streaming/ getting blank data. Please help me to get the data stream to Front End API in Elastic search.

The following request clears the cache for one indexes:

POST /search.articles.en-us/_cache/clear

ElasticSearch data stream to Front End API